# which way is better to design shopping Cart Table - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want to create a shopping cart in an online store. I have two ways to design shopping cart, but I don't know which one is better.

#### Solution 1:

Create a table like below:

[image: Shopping Cart table ERD with Id, UserId, ProductId, and quantity as integer type and CreatedDate as Date type]

In this way for each product for a user add new row.

**Note:** UserId and ProductId are unique

#### Solution 2:

Use two tables: Shopping Cart, Cart Item

[image: Two tables with 0..1 to 0..Many relationship. Shopping Cart table with Id and UserId as Integer type and CreatedDate as Date type. CartItems table with Id, ProductId, quantity as integer type, CreatedDate as Date type, and and ShoopingCartId as Integer type.]

In this way for each user just create a record in `Shopping Cart` Table.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Definitely solution 2. Solution 1 violates 1NF.

Comment: Solution 2 is best. But I am going with solution one. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 2 is the canonical solution for the Order / OrderItem pattern, which a shopping cart is, in essence. It allows the cart to be treated as a whole and distinct from another cart that may be submitted by the same user an arbitrarily short time later. Fulfilment can be recorded against a cart rather than each item individually, if that is what is required.

Comment: [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/210/razor-web-pages-e-commerce-adding-a-shopping-cart-to-the-bakery-template-site) is similar shopping cart design with CheckedOut `column` but do you mean Abandonment status of carts when you said Fulfillment of cart  ?

Comment: Are we going to keep all the cart items even after the order is placed with those, if so wont we have a huge table with unwanted data ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 That would depend on your business requirements. Typically the records would be kept for a while in case the customer has an enquiry or complaint. There may be an audit requirements to retain records for, say, seven years. Of course the data could be relocated to another system, a data warehouse perhaps, if having them in the OLTP system proves to be a problem. However, a modern installation, with good indexing and partitioning, should be able to handle many, many "cold" records.

Comment: @MichaelGreen I think you are right. Thanks for the explanation.